# Back button work only after 3 taps react native navigation

Tags: react-native-navigation

NavBar left back button works only after 3 taps, but I need so that it back after 1st click. How to fix it?

Comment: Are you redirecting to a different page 3 times before you get to your page?

Comment: no, only 1 time

Comment: When you click back, you probably go to the redirect page and that redirects you forward. That's why if you click 3 times fast enough, it moves past that page and get's you the page you need.

Comment: but I still don't understand, How can I  fix it so that it works after 1 click?

Comment: Did you resolve this and if so how? I just started testing my React Native app on Android and I have to hit the back button several times before it goes back.